# Compare dates in Python with datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, compare

So I have a list of dates:

```
[datetime.date(2013, 7, 9), datetime.date(2013, 7, 12), datetime.date(2013, 7, 15), datetime.date(2013, 7, 18), datetime.date(2013, 7, 22), datetime.date(2013, 7, 25)]
```

And I know today is:

```
date.today()
```

For the sake of this post, today is `datetime.date(2013, 7, 15)`

I need to be able to generate a list of any future dates, including today if it's on the list.

The return statement would be:

```
[datetime.date(2013, 7, 15), datetime.date(2013, 7, 18), datetime.date(2013, 7, 22), datetime.date(2013, 7, 25)]
```

I know I can just iterate over a list and compare dates using a timedelta but there has to be an easier way..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Comparing date with other date is possible.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects)

> date1 < date2 date1 is considered less than date2 when date1 precedes date2 in time.

```
>>> datetime.date(2013, 7, 15) < datetime.date(2013, 7, 16)
True
>>> datetime.date(2013, 7, 15) <= datetime.date(2013, 7, 16)
True
>>> datetime.date(2013, 7, 15) > datetime.date(2013, 7, 16)
False
```

---

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date(2013, 7, 15) # datetime.date.today()
>>> [d for d in dates if d >= today]
[datetime.date(2013, 7, 15), datetime.date(2013, 7, 18), datetime.date(2013, 7, 22), datetime.date(2013, 7, 25)]
```

Comment: That sure was quick! I can't believe I didn't think about doing inequality statements.. thanks so much!