# How to check if a date has Passed in Python (Simply)

Tags: python, date

I have looked around to see if I can find a simple method in Python to find out if a date has passed.

For example:-
If the date is `01/05/2015`, and the date; `30/04/2015` was in-putted into Python, it would return True, to say the date has passed.

This needs to be as simple and efficient as possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You say you have looked around, did you find any solutions? Why were they not acceptable?

Comment: The `time` and `datetime` modules can be used to convert strings into floats (representing seconds since the epoch) or datetime objects and to get the current time. A simple compare does the rest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare dates in Python with datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768928/compare-dates-in-python-with-datetime)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates)

Answer (score 14):

```
from datetime import datetime
present = datetime.now()
print datetime(2015, 4, 30) < present #should return true
```

Sourced some material from this question/answer: [How to compare two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates)

Answer (score 14):

you may use datetime, first parse String to date, then you can compare

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('05/01/2015', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('30/04/2015', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
d2>d1
```

Answer (score 7):

Just compare them?

```
>>> t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> t1>t2
False
>>> t1<t2
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple function which does this:

```
def has_expired(date):
    import datetime

    return date < datetime.datetime.now()
```